# Derivation of Kronecker delta tensor equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, trace

$$\delta^{[a_{1}}_{a_{1}}\cdot\cdot\cdot\delta_{a_{j}}^{a_{j}}\delta_{b_{j+1}}^{a_{j+1}}\cdot\cdot\cdot\delta_{b_{n}}^{a_{n}]} = \frac{(n-j)!j!}{n!}\delta_{b_{j+1}}^{[a_{j+1}}\cdot\cdot\cdot\delta_{b_{n}}^{a_{n}]}. $$

I'm trying to prove this equation and got started to see how it goes for base case of $n=2$.

It would be to show that $$\delta^{[a_{1}}_{a_{1}}\delta_{b_{2}}^{a_{2}]} =\frac{1}{2}\delta_{b_{2}}^{a_{2}} \tag{1}.$$

For equation (1), left side = $\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{a_{1}}^{a_{1}}\delta_{b_{2}}^{a_{2}}-\delta_{a_{1}}^{a_{2}}\delta_{b_{2}}^{a_{1}})=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{b_{2}}^{a_{2}}-\delta_{b_{2}}^{a_{2}})=0$. The reason I derived this is because $\delta_{a_{1}}^{a_{1}}=1$ for first item and $\delta_{a_{1}}^{a_{2}}\delta_{b_{2}}^{a_{1}} = \delta_{b_{2}}^{a_{2}}$ because of the contraction of $a_{1}$ index for second item.

Then this is weird, the equation isn't even right for $n=2 $ case as per my derivation. I know I made some silly mistakes in between but could someone please help me point this out? I believe once I got $n=2$ case sorted out I would be able to generalize the equation and finally prove it.

Comment: $\delta^{a_1}_{a_1}=D$, where $D$ is the number of spacetime dimensions. So in general for $n=2$ you should get $\frac{1}{2} \left(\delta^{a_1}_{a_1} \delta^{a_2}_{b_1}-\delta^{a_2}_{a_1}\delta^{a_1}_{b_1}\right)=\frac{D-1}{2}\delta^{a_2}_{b_1}.$

Comment: Thank you @Andrew! This is the exact answer I was looking for and it helped me solve the problem. Could you please move the comments to an answer so I can tag it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\delta^a_a=D$, where $D$ is the number of spacetime dimensions. So, in general, for $n=2$, we have

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \left( \delta^c_c \delta^a_b - \delta^a_c \delta^c_b \right) = \frac{D-1}{2}\delta^a_b.
\end{equation}